# View no obtiene el tamaño que quiero en un Grid Layout - android

Tags: android, android-layout

estoy practicando con grid layout y no consigo entender porque mi primer view no ocupa la mitad de la pantalla, este es el resultado que obtengo, pero yo quiero que la caja que dice "Hola" ocupe la mitad de la pantalla pero no hay manera  :( , agradecería mucho si me pueden arrojar algo de luz.

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Codigo:**
Le he dado al primer view, el que tiene el texto "hola" un rowSpan y un rowWeigth de 5, por lo que los demás botones empiezan a posicionarse desde la columna 5. En teoría la maya tiene 10 filas y el primer view ocupa 5, por lo que yo entiendo que debería ocupar la mitad de la pantalla, ya que los otros ocupan 1 cada uno.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
  >
 
    <TextView
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
 
        android:layout_rowSpan="5"
        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
 
        android:layout_rowWeight="5"
        android:layout_columnWeight="4"
 
      
        android:text="Hola"
        style="@style/calc_dark"/>
 
<!-- FILA 1-->
 
 
    <TextView
        android:text="%"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
      
        style="@style/calc_dark"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
/>
 
    <TextView
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
      
        style="@style/calc_ligth"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
 
    <TextView
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
      
        style="@style/calc_ligth"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
 
    <TextView
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
      
        style="@style/calc_ligth"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
 
    <TextView
        android:text="("
        android:layout_row="9"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
      
        android:padding="38dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        style="@style/calc_ligth" />
 
 
 
    <!-- FILA 2-->
 
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/boton_c"
        style="@style/calc_dark"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
      
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:width="36dp"
        android:text="c" />
 
    <TextView
        android:text="8"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
      
        style="@style/calc_ligth"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
 
    <TextView
        android:text="5"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
      
        style="@style/calc_ligth"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
 
    <TextView
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
      
        style="@style/calc_ligth"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
 
    <TextView
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_row="9"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
      
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        style="@style/calc_ligth" />
 
 
    <!-- FILA 3 -->
 
 
    <TextView
        android:text="9"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
      
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        style="@style/calc_ligth" />
 
    <TextView
        android:text="6"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
      
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        style="@style/calc_ligth" />
 
    <TextView
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
      
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        style="@style/calc_ligth" />
 
    <TextView
        android:text=")"
        android:layout_row="9"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
      
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        style="@style/calc_ligth" />
 
 
    <!-- FILA 4-->
 
 
    <TextView
        android:text="X"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
      
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:width="36dp"
        style="@style/calc_dark" />
 
    <TextView
        android:text="+"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
      
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        style="@style/calc_dark" />
 
    <TextView
        android:text="-"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
      
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        style="@style/calc_dark" />
 
    <TextView
        android:text="."
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
      
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        style="@style/calc_dark" />
 
    <TextView
        android:text="="
        android:layout_row="9"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
      
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        style="@style/calc_igual" />
 
 
 
</GridLayout>
```

**Estilo:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 
    <style name="calc_dark" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline">
            <item name="android:textColor"> @color/white </item>
            <item name="android:background"> @drawable/tv_custom </item>
            <item name="android:radius"> 15dp </item>
            <item name="android:padding"> 35dp </item>
            <item name="android:layout_height"> wrap_content </item>
            <item name="android:gravity"> center </item>
            <item name="android:layout_margin"> 3dp </item>
    </style>
 
    <style name="calc_ligth" parent="calc_dark">
            <item name="android:backgroundTint"> @color/gray_light </item>
    </style>
 
    <style name="calc_igual" parent="calc_dark">
        <item name="android:backgroundTint"> @color/blue_brillant </item>
        <item name="android:textColor"> @color/black </item>
    </style>
 
</resources>
```

**tv_custom:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/gray_dark"/>
                <corners android:radius="12dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se solucionó al darle un tamaño fijo a cada Textview :D